# Only highlight currently hovered nested list item

Tags: html, css

Suppose an `ul` has `li` items, some of which have again `ul` with inner `li` items:

```
    <div class="nav-main">
        <ul>
            <li>First Level First Item</li>
            <li>First Level Second item
                <ul><li>Level 2 First item</li></ul>
            </li>    
            <li>Level 1 Second item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hovering over an `li` item of the outer list highlights this one, but hovering over the nested list item hovers this one and the enclosing list item.

```
li:hover { border: 1px solid black; }
```

How can there always be only one item be highlighted? Prefereably without any JavaScript.

```css
li:hover { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
        <div class="nav-main">
            <ul>
                <li>First Level First Item</li>
                <li>First Level Second item
                    <ul><li>Level 2 First item</li></ul>
                </li>    
                <li>Level 1 Second item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to add a `<span>` around each text item in the list, which you can then use as a CSS selector:

```css
li>span:hover { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<div class="nav-main">
  <ul>
    <li><span>First Level First Item</span></li>
    <li><span>First Level Second item</span>
      <ul><li><span>Level 2 First item</span></li></ul>
    </li>    
    <li><span>Level 1 Second item</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: with this the hover on the second li will not cover the whole li

Comment: I believe that is the intent

Comment: I see.. still I wonder if there is no way without changing the markup.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following solution using `::before` pseudo-elements:

- Always use the `position: relative` of `li` elements, and a `height: 1em;` for the sizing of the pseudo-elements (the borders),
- On `hover` of `li`s, display the border/pseudo-element,
- On `hover` of sub-`ul`s, add a white border to hide the parent `li` border.

Working snippet:

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px; /* Added this to prevent some dead-zones triggering the ul:hover */
}

li::before, ul::before {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1em;
  top: -1px;
  left: -4px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1px 0;
}

li:hover::before {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

li ul:hover::before {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-main">
  <ul>
    <li>First Level First Item</li>
    <li>First Level Second item
      <ul>
        <li>Level 2 First item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1 Second item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it's somehow like my trick :p

Comment: Well @TemaniAfif, if it is, I didn't mean to! I promise. :) In fact, I didn't understand everything in your first snippet. So, I tried to make mine, and to avoid the not-working behavior when you hover the sub-li and go back to hover the parent li. (That doesn't work in yours)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a trick to hide the outer highlight as I don't think you can disable it since the hover of the child element will always trigger a hover of the parent element:

```css
li:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.nav-main>ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

ul>li>ul>li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  display:none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul>li>ul>li:hover:before {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-main">
  <ul>
    <li>First Level First Item</li>
    <li>First Level Second item
      <ul>
        <li>Level 2 First item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1 Second item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is another trick where you can replace the border with a pseudo-element:

```css
li {
  position: relative;
}

li span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display:none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

li span:hover:before {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-main">
  <ul>
    <li><span>First Level First Item</span></li>
    <li><span>First Level Second item</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span>Level 2 First item</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Level 1 Second item</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Close the < li> before nesting will only higlight 1 at a time

```
<div class="nav-main">
        <ul>
            <li>First Level First Item</li>
            <li>First Level Second item</li>
                <ul><li>Level 2 First item</li></ul>  
            <li>Level 1 Second item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```html
<style type="text/css">li:hover { border: 1px solid blue; }</style>

<div class="nav-main">
  <ul>
    <li>First Level First Item</li>
    <li>First Level Second item</li>
      <ul><li>Level 2 First item</li></ul>   
    <li>Level 1 Second item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not a valid html, ul can only have li as direct child